# Activities to be shown in a full calendar

Tags: activities, civicase

CiviCRM 4.62 on Drupal 7.37 in a Linux Virtual Box using only the CiviCASE module.

I need a full calendar view for civiCRM activities. I need a page with month, week and day views for the current user. I also need the calendar to have the ability to easily select a different user's calendar. I have other requirements that would be nice features but I need at least those two (full calendar and change users).

In practice -- The case manager wants to see at a glance what their day, week or month looks like, particularly to find a free day and time for an appointment. They also want to see the availability of other staff in a quick and efficient manner because they may be scheduling an appointment for that other staff person.

As proof of concept (but for Events, not Activities) there is the 'CiviCRM Event Calendar' extension by osseed [(Link to Git page)](https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar) built 2 years ago and updated six months ago. I haven't tested it but I assume it works. It is based on the open source jquery plugin called Full Calendar [(link to description page)](http://fullcalendar.io/) .

I have seen mentions of other attempts to provide this full calendar feature but they fizzled out somewhere along the line. The one I tried fell short of actually showing a calendar -- Contact Calendar [(Link to description page)](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-calendar). In that case it showed a new tab on the contacts page but no calendar appeared.

I would prefer this feature to be an extension to CiviCRM so it would be useful to a larger audience than just Drupal users.

How many hours should this take for a consultant to develop?

Any other thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. John in Oregon.

Answer (score 4):

So last time I looked Civi for Drupal ships with a calendar of activities if you install the views calendar modules (and dependencies). I think its called my activities or something similar.

You should be able to tweak this to just show the activities of type for the case in question.

Just to let you know we original developed the Civi Contact Calendar Extension but we deprecated it as the functionality above was developed.

Let me know how you get on.

Best

Jamie

Comment: I got the Drupal calendar going. Works so for that I'm grateful. It falls short of my expectations/hopes/needs. No drag and drop, no 'click to change view', no change user, and most importantly no click to view the activity details and edit the activity. If you think it can do that I'll try to find out how but for now it falls short.

Any ideas? Thanks for thinking about this with me.

Comment: Don't know if you're still working on this but you can achieve the view/edit activity with a custom profile and a colorbox link to it in your calendar view.  As for the draggable, have you checked out the Draggable Views module?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Views and Calendar alone could do what you need.

You can link the activity subject to the activity page on the Calendar views. Here's how you can do this:

Go to your views, you should already have added the "CiviCRM Activities: Subject" field.

1. Under Fields, add "CiviCRM Activities: Activity ID (Activity ID) and "Exclude from display."
2. Move this field above the Subject.
3. Click on your Subject field and under "Rewrite Results" click on "Output this field as a link". The link path should be something along the lines of:

activity?action=view&reset=1&id=[id]

In terms of having a calendar for each case manager, I suppose you can add the user and then exposing it so the activities would filter or use the contextual filters. I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Nice. I had thought we had to include the contact ids. Glad you proved me wrong. To go direct to the Edit for the Activity it looks like the link needs to be
civicrm/activity/add?reset=1&action=update&reset=1&id=1400

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicalendar